# Join a subquery of record count with main query - Avoid redundant query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables, namely Sequence table and Work table. I have to join them and fetch the P_KEY and L_KEY from Work table for each TN_ID in Sequence table. Now, I also want to attach the count of {P_KEY,L_KEY} for each TN_ID with each TN_ID of Sequence Table. For this I had to write the Join of Sequence Table and Work Table two times. I want to avoid that. How can I achieve this?

```
Select Distinct
    A.TM_ID, rtrim(A.TN_ID) as TN_ID,  
    W.P_KEY, W.L_KEY
    FROM Sequence_Table A Left Outer JOIN Work_Table W
    ON A.TM_ID=W.TM_ID AND rtrim(A.TN_ID)=rtrim(W.TN_ID)
        
    Join
    
    (SELECT A.TM_ID as TM_ID_c, A.TN_ID as TN_ID_c, count(*) as Count_
    FROM Sequence_Table A LEFT OUTER JOIN Work_Table W
    ON A.TM_ID=W.TM_ID AND rtrim (A.TN_ID) = rtrim (W.TN_ID)
    Group by A.TM_ID, A.TN_ID) C                                     
    On A.TM_ID = C.TM_ID_C and A.TN_ID = C.TN_ID_C
```

PS: Solutions with Oracle SQL only and not with PL/SQL are prefered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `with` clause to factor a subquery, see [WITH Clause : Subquery Factoring](http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/with-clause.php)

Using it you get more readable and in most cases faster queries.

Answer (score 1):

As user @54l3d mentioned for repetitive part of code it is common practice to use `with` clause. 
For your query it should be (it gave me same results as yours):

```
with cte as (
  select st.tm_id, rtrim(st.tn_id) tn_id, wt.p_key, wt.l_key
    from sequence_table st left join work_table wt 
      on st.tm_id = wt.tm_id and rtrim(st.tn_id) = rtrim(wt.tn_id))
select distinct a.tm_id, a.tn_id, p_key, l_key 
  from cte a 
  join (select tm_id, tn_id, count(1) cnt from cte group by tm_id, tn_id) c
    on a.tm_id = c.tm_id and a.tn_id = c.tn_id
```

<sup>[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5f1ce7/1)</sup>

BTW - I think that here you don't even need self joining query, you can shorten your syntax to:

```
select distinct st.tm_id, rtrim(st.tn_id) tn_id, wt.p_key, wt.l_key
  from sequence_table st left join work_table wt 
    on st.tm_id = wt.tm_id and rtrim(st.tn_id) = rtrim(wt.tn_id)
```

... but maybe I didn't notice something or you provided this query only as example of repetitive code.

Comment: Thanks. Really appreciate the use of With clause here. Since user @54l3d mentioned that first, I have to accept his answer. But yours is a +1 also.
But I did not get the second part of your answer. If you see my question, I want to join the count of records with the original query. Simply writing the original query only ( that you have given in the later part of your answer), will not give me the count of records. I need the count with the query itself, because I have some other module next that works based on the result of this query and count is required there.